# How to get the count of a string from a text file . The output is wrong

Tags: windows, command-line, perl

I have written a code for finding the IP address count from a text file. if similar IP dress exist in file toto.txt :

My code to do this is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
my $str ;
#my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILE\n";
my $address = "192.168.2.16";
 open my $fh, '<', 'C:\shekhar_Axestrack_Intern\WindowCreation\toto.txt', or die "Could not open file $!";
 print "address is $address \n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $str ($address, $line) 
    {
        $count{$str}++;
    }   
}
foreach $str (sort keys %count) 
{
    printf "%s\n", $count{$str};
}
close $fh;
```

I expect this to return 4 count because there are 4 existence of this address in list toto.txt

```
Address is : 100.64.26.172  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:11:31 2015 End
Address is : 192.168.2.16  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:12:33 2015 End
Address is : 100.65.15.169  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:13:51 2015 End
Address is : 192.168.2.16  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:15:17 2015 End
Address is : 100.65.34.233  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:18:04 2015 End
Address is : 192.168.2.16  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:19:46 2015 End
Address is : 100.64.8.194  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:31:58 2015 End
Address is : 192.168.2.16  and the Time is : Thu Jan 15 18:33:30 2015 End
```

But the output is this :

```
address is 192.168.2.16
8
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

How to change my code to get the 4 count of IP (which is actually 4) ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count/print? For debugging: print not only the counts, but also the keys and you will see what you counted. Hint: `foreach my $str ($address, $line)` iterates over the list `($address, $line)`, you are not searching for $address in the line at any place. You should use regular expressions to achieve that.

Comment: @WernerHenze i am new to perl.. When i try to print keys (print "$keys";) it gives error(Global symbol "$keys" requires explicit package name at C:\s...)and if it was a c language, i could have done in foreach something like this: break a string line in words(individual strings fore each word separated by space) and then compare with $address, if same there is a match. How to do it in perl ?

Comment: Obiously $str is the key, so printing $str would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one-liner can help you:

```
perl -nE '$count++ if /192.168.2.16/;END{say $count}' your_file_name_here
```

Run this one-liner from the command prompt.

This will print the number of occurrences of `192.168.2.16` (so two occurrences on the same line will be counted twice). If you only want to count the lines where the address occurred at least once, use this instead:

```
perl -nE 'if(/192\.168\.2\.16/){$count++;next LINE};END{say $count}' your_file_name_here
```

**Explanation**

- `-n` means apply the given code to each line of the file (technically, to each record as defined by the record separator (`$/` which is a newline by default).
- `-E` means treat the upcoming string as a piece of Perl code.
- `$count++ if /.../` means increment the `$count` variable if the current line contains the IP address you're looking for.
- `next LINE` works because the `-n` switch automatically wraps your code in a per-line loop with the label `LINE`.
- `END{...}` run the code between the curlies at the very end (after the last line has been processed).

Note that you may need to refine the regex depending on your use case. You can for example anchor it to make sure it doesn't match within some random string of digits and periods:

```
/[^0-9.]192\.168\.2\.16[^0-9.]/
```

I know the OP is using Windows. For future readers of this question using a system with a POSIX-compliant `grep`, you can use:

```
grep -Fc '192.168.2.16' your_file_name_here
```

to get a count of lines that contain that IP address.